# show button condition flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I would like my button to show only if my _isloading condition is false.
With my code the button appears but too early.

my widget:

i want my button after my timer set _isLoading = false.
Actually, my button show directly to start timer.

How do I get my button to only display when my timer set my _isLoading = false ?

Comment: Do you actually have "_isLoading" set to "true" when the app first starts?

Comment: yes, before my timer _isLoading is set true

Comment: Can you post more of your code, showing the initialisation of the app and main screen?  Depending on exactly how you're declaring "_isLoading" and different places you are setting its value, will be relevant in terms of the order in which Flutter processes and builds things.  Remember that the "initial" (ie. default) value of a declared boolean variable is false

Comment: i have add my case 4, bool _isLoading = true; is declared, my initialisation app and main screen has nothing to do with my code here

Comment: Where do your "buttonSubScreen" and "gotoapp" methods sit?  (ie. under which class?)  You have the timer under the "_VerifPhotoScreenValidateState" class, and its associated "_isLoading" variable, but if the "buttonSubScreen" and "gotoapp" methods sit outside the "_VerifPhotoScreenValidateState" class then they will not be referencing the same "_isLoading" variable ..... off the top of my head I can't recall if Flutter always requires variable declaration, or just the initial use will declare it and set the value

Comment: My variable _isLoading is ok. Not the problem. My var is call with my CustomModalProgressHUD(
              inAsyncCall: _isLoading,.

Comment: My va isLoading work great, this not problèm.

Comment: My problèm is: my button show to start timer. whereas I want it to show only when my timer is finished and it sets my variable isLoading.

Comment: I think I would have to wait for the condition to be false, with an await maybe?

Comment: I understand what it is that you want to achieve.  I still don't think that the variable is working in the way you expect it to.  I assume you have debugged / stepped through each line as the app is running, and obviously when the "gotoapp()" method is called, the value of "_isLoading" is false, yes?  Just because you set "_isLoading" to true when you first create your "_VerifPhotoScreenValidateState" object, doesn't mean that the variable within that class is available to everything outside that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to keep in mind the Flutter's tree widget structure. The tree hierachy should consists of only Widgets.

In your `_validateUser()`, since this method doesn't return a `Widget`, it cannot be put as a child of the `Column` widget. This method should be trigger by a button (after the user finish the form for example).

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:modal_progress_hud/modal_progress_hud.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Home()));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isValidated = false;

  _validateUser() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        _isValidated = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _validateUser();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
        child: ModalProgressHUD(
          inAsyncCall: _isLoading,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                // FlatButton(
                //   color: Colors.red,
                //   child: Text("Validate User"),
                //   onPressed: _validateUser,
                // ),
                // SizedBox(height: 10),
                if (_isValidated)
                  FlatButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text("Validate User"),
                    onPressed: _validateUser,
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: hello, i test your code, its fine, but i don't want see a red button and click this. It's possible?

Comment: if I understand correctly, my choice is not possible, so I will change so that my button is grayed out and disable the delay time

Comment: @rpz Do you want to run the timer right after the screen is opened?

Comment: @rpz You can use the `addPostFrameCallback` within `initState`. Updated my answer for that.